# How to set the DateField value to the Previous Value if certain condition fails in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am creating a DateField and adding listener to it.If certain conditions fails I need to reset the value of DateField with previous value which is there in that field.Below is my code

```
final DateField dateField1 = new DateField();
    dateField1.getPropertyEditor().setFormat(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy")); 
    dateField1.getDatePicker().addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<DatePickerEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(DatePickerEvent dpe) {

        //  Window.alert("Getting Roster Date here-->"+grid.getColumnModel().);
        Window.alert("Getting RosterDate-->"+   caseStoreModule.getModifiedRecords().get(0).get("rosterDate"));
         if(caseStoreModule.getModifiedRecords().get(0).get("rosterDate")!=null){
                DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
                rosterdate=format.parse(caseStoreModule.getModifiedRecords().get(0).get("rosterDate").toString());
                nextdate.setTime(rosterdate.getTime()+(1000*60*60*24));
                prevdate.setTime(rosterdate.getTime()-(1000*60*60*24));
            }
        checkInDate=(Date)(dateField1.getValue());
        if(checkInDate.getTime()<rosterdate.getTime() || checkInDate.getTime()>nextdate.getTime()){
            MsgBox.info("Enter valid Check In Date");
           dateField1.setValue();//here i need to reset the value to the     previous value.
            return ;
        }



        }
    });
```

If the if condition is true,then I need to put the previous value which is there in the Field instead of reseting it.Please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is having a String variable that holds the field value before doing any manipulation. So if you need to reset the field just use it. Something like this

```
String tmpStringValue = dateField1.getValue();
...
if(something went wrong){
   dateField1.setValue(tmpStringValue );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store values as an attribute of `Element`.

At first time this attribute `oldValue` will be blank. 
Set this attribute every time if validation is successful.

For more information read inline comments.

Here is the sample code:

```
dateField1.getCell().getDatePicker().addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {

        DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");
        String oldValue = dateField1.getElement().getAttribute("oldValue");

        if (oldValue == null || oldValue.length() == 0) {
            // initially date field is empty
            dateField1.getElement().setAttribute("oldValue",
                    format.format(event.getValue()));
        } else {
            Date oldDate = format.parse(oldValue);
            Date newDate = event.getValue();

            // you validation logic
            if (oldDate.getTime() < newDate.getTime()) {
                // revert back to last value if validation is failed
                dateField1.getCell().getDatePicker().setValue(oldDate);
            } else {
                // set the old value with new one 
                dateField1.getElement().setAttribute("oldValue",
                        format.format(event.getValue()));
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Call below line if value is initially populated by its default value just after setting the value.

```
dateField1.getElement().setAttribute("oldValue",
                    format.format(event.getValue()));
```

Comment: I am using GXT 2.2.3 DateField.There is no getCell method in that.Please suggest the alternative way to do this.

Comment: This is the dateField that I am adding to a column in EditorGrid

Comment: What class are you using for `DateField`? I am using `com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.DateField`.

Comment: I am using this  **com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.DateField**

Answer (score 0):

In GXT, every `Field` has a [`setOriginalValue(D originalValue)`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/Field.html#setOriginalValue%28D%29) method which could help you in this matter too. You can always return to the original value by [`reset()`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/Field.html#reset%28%29)ing the Field. *Please keep in mind that `reset()` will clear the validation messages too!*

How to use it in situations like this?

1. Set the original value when the entered value is validated fine
2. Call `Field.reset()`, if anything went wrong to reload the last working value in your field.